# upgrade program for converting vb6 app to C#

Tags: c#, vb6, vb6-migration

What is the best pathway to achieve this?

I know that VS2005 contains an upgrade mechanism.  Do any later versions of VS contain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has devoted a [site to VB6->.NET migration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/vbrun/ms788233).
They recommend a [Free tool](http://www.artinsoft.com/msdn/?msdn) from ArtInSoft.

However I'm not sure I'd like to maintain a .NET application written in VB6-style. But on the other hand a tool could give you a good start and you can refactor the result where the tool does not produce code of your liking.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest release of Visual Studio, the VB6 Migration wizard is now missing from the IDE.

A good external tool to perform a migration is [VBUC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff793478) .

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this, which was used successfully in one of my previous teams, is:-

1. use the free Microsoft tools for upgrading from VB6 to VB.NET (e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/vbrun/ms788233)
2. compile the resulting code into assemblies
3. decompile the assemblies into C# using a tool such as .NET
   Reflector, ILSpy, etc.
4. cover the code in unit tests
5. refactor until the code is managable (the initial code is likely to
   be quite ugly)